# Perspective transform of an array with coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates, transform, perspective

I have an array with coordinates (2D) and want to calculate the new coordinates in a different quadrilateral. I do only know de corners of both quadrilaterals.

So for example, the old quadrilateral corner coordinates are

```
topleft(25,25), Topright(200,20), Botomleft(35,210), Botomright(215,200)
```

the new quadrilateral:

```
Topleft(-50,50), Topright(50,50), Botomleft(-50,-50), Botomright(-50,-50)
```

Is there a specific function in opencv (cv2) to do so, or even a formula.

I am searching for quite a while and I can only seem to find Matrix calculations or function to transform a whole image or array.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, opencv has what you need:

First, compute the transform matrix:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
src = np.array(((25, 25), (200, 20), (35, 210), (215, 200)), dtype=np.float32)
dest = np.array(((-50, -50), (50, -50), (-50, 50), (50, 50)), dtype=np.float32)
mtx = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dest)
```

You will notice I took the liberty to make `dest`'s orientation match `src`'s one before computing the transform (inverted top and bottom).

Now that matrix can be used to convert any array of points (2D in our case):

```
original = np.array([((42, 42), (30, 100), (150, 75))], dtype=np.float32)
converted = cv2.perspectiveTransform(original, mtx)
```

Result:

```
>>> converted
>>> array([[[-41.06365204 -40.27705765]
      [-49.48046112  -8.70405197]
      [ 18.60642052 -19.92881393]]])
```

As a final advice, please note the shape of the input points array `original`: it has to be a 3D array, as I found out [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/252/cv2perspectivetransform-with-python/).